Is there a way in ggplot2 to fit several columns of text, minimising the space between them?
I'm trying to use RStudio and ggplot2.
I have a list of studies, some information about their data and another couple of columns of numbers.
What I would like is a plot where I could fix the size of the font (in points or mm or whatever) and have the plot height and width calculated and set to display the data with minimal gaps.
I know that the plot windows are re-sizable and that many of the things then automatically re-scale, but I don't really want that to be an option?
columns of text
So in this image I'd like the numbers columns to be a bit closer to the others.
I'm trying to do this programatically as I'll have lots of similar things with different length strings/different numbers of items, so the image size will sometimes be taller, sometimes wider etc.
I don't really know what I'm doing, I have tried using strwidth to estimate the width of the longest string, then used that to create a graph that was as high as the number of items and as wide as the width of the longest string.
Then I plotted the text based on newly calculated strwidths.
Of course, when I resize the window everything changes, but I don't really want to be able to resize.
I'm not super familiar with R (obviously that shows!)
Any help warmly received (or just letting me know that it's not possible/my idea doesn't make sense)!
structure(list(display_order = 1:12, study_ID = c("Pillay 2019", 
"Carr 2016", "Parry 2015", "Mansi 2018", "Maruyama 2017", "Turner 2024", 
"Talbot 2020", "Morgan 2021", "Viester 2021", "Aittasalo 2019", 
"Forbes 2018", "Linde 2022"), summary_data = c("Direction only", 
"MD (95% CI)", "MD (95% CI)", "MD (95% CI)", "Dichotomous data", 
"N", "MD (95% CI)", "Direction (p>0.05)", "Direction (specific p-value)", 
"MD (SE)", "Direction (specific p-value)", "No direction (specific p-value)"
), ft_n = c(11L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 55L, 78L, 89L, 
150L, 215L), fc_n = c(8L, 20L, 27L, 31L, 32L, 40L, 44L, 55L, 
78L, 92L, 150L, 215L), name_length = c(1.01267026665898, 0.933760895231004, 
1.01267026665898, 1.07842807618229, 1.48612649522681, 1.10473119999161, 
1.09157963808695, 1.22309525713357, 1.18364057141958, 1.32830775237087, 
1.18364057141958, 1.0389733904683), summary_data_length = c(1.23624681903823, 
1.18364057141958, 1.18364057141958, 1.18364057141958, 1.67024836189208, 
0.144667180951282, 1.18364057141958, 1.65709679998742, 2.43303895236248, 
0.802245276184384, 2.43303895236248, 2.70922175236038), ft_n_length = c(0.236728114283917, 
0.236728114283917, 0.236728114283917, 0.236728114283917, 0.236728114283917, 
0.236728114283917, 0.236728114283917, 0.236728114283917, 0.236728114283917, 
0.236728114283917, 0.355092171425875, 0.355092171425875), fc_n_length = c(0.118364057141958, 
0.236728114283917, 0.236728114283917, 0.236728114283917, 0.236728114283917, 
0.236728114283917, 0.236728114283917, 0.236728114283917, 0.236728114283917, 
0.236728114283917, 0.355092171425875, 0.355092171425875), x = c(3.88541666666667, 
3.88541666666667, 3.88541666666667, 3.88541666666667, 3.88541666666667, 
3.88541666666667, 3.88541666666667, 3.88541666666667, 3.88541666666667, 
3.88541666666667, 3.88541666666667, 3.88541666666667)), row.names = c(NA, 
12L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)

# keep the things we want to plot
MA_data_text <- subset(MA_data, select=c("display_order","study_ID","summary_data","ft_n","fc_n" ))

################################################################################
# find the width of the strings
MA_data_text$name_length <- strwidth(MA_data_text$study_ID, units="inches")
# find the maximum width
study_ID.max_value <- max(MA_data_text$name_length,na.rm=TRUE)
# summary data value to plot at is...
summary_data_x_coord <- study_ID.max_value

# n1
# find the width of the strings
MA_data_text$summary_data_length <- strwidth(MA_data_text$summary_data, units="inches")
# find the maximum width
summary_data.max_value <- max(MA_data_text$summary_data_length,na.rm=TRUE)
# n1 data value to plot at is...
n1_x_coord <- study_ID.max_value + summary_data.max_value

# n2
# find the width of the strings
MA_data_text$ft_n_length <- strwidth(MA_data_text$ft_n, units="inches")
# find the maximum width
ft_n.max_value <- max(MA_data_text$ft_n_length,na.rm=TRUE)
# n2 data value to plot at is...
n2_x_coord <- study_ID.max_value + summary_data.max_value + ft_n.max_value

# find the width of n2 to find the maximum needed
MA_data_text$fc_n_length <- strwidth(MA_data_text$fc_n, units="inches")
# find the maximum width
fc_n.max_value <- max(MA_data_text$fc_n_length,na.rm=TRUE)
# end data value to plot at is...
end_x_coord <- study_ID.max_value + summary_data.max_value + ft_n.max_value + fc_n.max_value

################################################################################

# make a box to put the text in
MA_data_text$x <- end_x_coord

MA_text_plot <- ggplot(MA_data_text)
# set the figure
MA_text_plot <- MA_text_plot + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=display_order), color="white", alpha=0)

################################################################################
# find the width of the strings
MA_data_text$name_length <- strwidth(MA_data_text$study_ID)
# find the maximum width
study_ID.max_value <- max(MA_data_text$name_length,na.rm=TRUE)
# summary data value to plot at is...
summary_data_x_coord <- study_ID.max_value

# n1
# find the width of the strings
MA_data_text$summary_data_length <- strwidth(MA_data_text$summary_data)
# find the maximum width
summary_data.max_value <- max(MA_data_text$summary_data_length,na.rm=TRUE)
# n1 data value to plot at is...
n1_x_coord <- study_ID.max_value + summary_data.max_value

# n2
# find the width of the strings
MA_data_text$ft_n_length <- strwidth(MA_data_text$ft_n)
# find the maximum width
ft_n.max_value <- max(MA_data_text$ft_n_length,na.rm=TRUE)
# n2 data value to plot at is...
n2_x_coord <- study_ID.max_value + summary_data.max_value + ft_n.max_value

# find the width of n2 to find the maximum needed
MA_data_text$fc_n_length <- strwidth(MA_data_text$fc_n)
# find the maximum width
fc_n.max_value <- max(MA_data_text$fc_n_length,na.rm=TRUE)
# end data value to plot at is...
end_x_coord <- study_ID.max_value + summary_data.max_value + ft_n.max_value + fc_n.max_value

################################################################################

# add some text
MA_text_plot <- MA_text_plot + geom_text(aes(x=0,y=display_order,label=study_ID),hjust="left",vjust="center")

MA_text_plot <- MA_text_plot + geom_text(aes(x=summary_data_x_coord,y=display_order,label=summary_data),hjust="left",vjust="center")

MA_text_plot <- MA_text_plot + geom_text(aes(x=n1_x_coord,y=display_order,label=ft_n),hjust="left",vjust="center")

MA_text_plot <- MA_text_plot + geom_text(aes(x=n2_x_coord,y=display_order,label=fc_n),hjust="left",vjust="center")

MA_text_plot```


Welcome to SO.  This sounds more like a table than a plot to me...  Also, strwidth is in graphics, which gives information about R base graphics, not ggplot2 graphics, so I'm not sure your approach will ever work.

Care to provide some background and context on why you picked this aproach? I mean, there might a perfectly good reason to build text tables from scratch with ggplot, but most common use cases are covered by various  packages that target table formatting or build grobs that one could combine with ggplot objects.

@margusl thanks, I'd like to put together a plot like a forest plot that have rows of data with a mix of graphic and text. I've seen examples online that require the user to specify the x coords for the text columns and I wondered if there was a way to work out how much space the text took up so that you could:
a)plot the actual graphic elements, calculate the min/max of those sections, then work backwards from them by the length of the text to automatically work out where to put the text
OR
b)use side by side images but somehow exactly line up the y coords in each case
c) something else!

To reduce the vertical spacing of text in a chart, set the aspect ratio as a single value or (height/width) of the plot with theme(). For example:
MA_text_plot+
  theme(aspect.ratio=1/4)

